# lightning:duallistbox - how to preset selected values?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-duallistbox

The official developer [specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:dualListbox/specification) says the component (API v43) has "**values**" attribute.

> A list of default options that are included in the selected options list box. This list is populated with values from the options attribute.

If I understand this correctly the I should be able to set this attribute with a subset of objects I provide in option list.

Now when I try to set it :

1)  The right list of the component is empty 
2)  The console sends me this greeting

> WARNING: "values" must either be a public property of lightningDualListbox or a global HTML attribute

Is this a bug or am I misreading the doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Dual List Box with Default Selected options](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:dualListbox/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDualListboxDefaultValues) example specified in the docs worked for me:

**Component Markup:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="values" type="List" default="[]"/>

        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>

        <lightning:dualListbox name="multipleOptions"  
                               label= "Select Options" 
                               sourceLabel="Available" 
                               selectedLabel="Selected" 
                               options="{!v.options}" 
                               value="{!v.values}" 
                               onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>

    </aura:component>
```

**Controller JS:**

```
({
    init: function (cmp) {
        var items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            var item = {
                "label": "Option " + i,
                "value": "opt" + i,
            };
            items.push(item);
        }
        cmp.set("v.options", items);
        // "values" must be a subset of values from "options"
        cmp.set("v.values", ["opt10", "opt5", "opt7"]);
    },

    handleChange: function (cmp, event) {
        // This will contain an array of the "value" attribute of the selected options
        var selectedOptionValue = event.getParam("value");
        alert("Option selected with value: '" + selectedOptionValue.toString() + "'");
    }
})
```